# Add a custom checkout field after the billing fields in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a custom field at the bottom of the billing section but I get two fields instead. The heading and the input are right but I get another unwanted input field inside the `woocommerce-billing-fields__field-wrapper`.

**functions.php**

```
// Add a custom text field to WooCommerce checkout billing section
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_checkout_field');

function custom_checkout_field($fields) {
    $fields['billing']['custom_text_field'] = array(
        'type'        => 'text',
        'class'       => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label'       => __('Custom Text Field', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder' => __('Enter your custom text', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'    => true,
    );

    return $fields;
}

// Save the custom text field value to the order meta
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_custom_checkout_field');

function save_custom_checkout_field($order_id) {
    if (!empty($_POST['custom_text_field'])) {
        update_post_meta($order_id, '_custom_text_field', sanitize_text_field($_POST['custom_text_field']));
    }
}

// Display the custom text field on the checkout page
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'display_custom_checkout_field');

function display_custom_checkout_field($checkout) {
    ?>
    <div id="custom_checkout_field_display">
        <h3><?php _e('Custom Text Field'); ?></h3>
        <div class="custom-text-field-wrapper">
            <?php woocommerce_form_field('custom_text_field', array(
                'type'        => 'text',
                'class'       => array('form-row-wide'),
                'label'       => __('Custom Text Field', 'woocommerce'),
                'placeholder' => __('Enter your custom text', 'woocommerce'),
                'required'    => true,
            ), $checkout->get_value('custom_text_field')); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

[image]

**Structure**
[image]

Comment: You are adding the field using woocommerce_checkout_fields and woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form. Pick one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding 2 times this custom checkout field, there are some mistakes and missing things in your code.

Since WooCommerce 3, the hook `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` is outdated and replaced by `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` *(compatible WooCommerce with High-Performance Order Storage)*.

As your field is a required field, the field validation need to be implemented.

You also need to save this custom field value as custom user metadata, so it will work with: `$checkout->get_value($field_key)`.

Try the following code replacement:

```php
// Display the custom text field on the checkout page
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'display_custom_checkout_field' );
function display_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    $field_key = 'my_custom_field';

    echo '<div id="custom_checkout_field_display">
        <h3>' . esc_html__('Custom Text Field Section', 'woocommerce') . '</h3>
        <div class="custom-text-field-wrapper">';
    
    woocommerce_form_field( $field_key, array(
        'type'        => 'text',
        'class'       => array('form-row-wide'),
        'label'       => esc_html__('My Custom field', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder' => esc_html__('My Custom field placeholder text', 'woocommerce'), // Optional
        'required'    => true,
    ), $checkout->get_value($field_key) );

    echo '</div>
    </div>';
}

// Custom checkout field validation
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_checkout_field_validation' );
function custom_checkout_field_validation() {
    $field_key = 'my_custom_field';
    if ( isset($_POST[$field_key]) && empty($_POST[$field_key]) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __('<strong>My Custom field</strong> is a required field.', 'woocommerce'),'error' );
    }
}

// Save the custom checkout field value as custom order metadata
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_custom_checkout_field_value_order_meta' );
function save_custom_checkout_field_value_order_meta( $order ) {
    $field_key = 'my_custom_field';
    if ( isset($_POST[$field_key]) && ! empty($_POST[$field_key]) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_' . $field_key, sanitize_text_field($_POST[$field_key]) );
    }
}

// Save the custom checkout field value as custom customer metadata
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_customer', 'save_custom_checkout_field_value_customer_meta') ;
function save_custom_checkout_field_value_customer_meta( $customer ) {
    $field_key = 'my_custom_field';
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && isset($_POST[$field_key]) && ! empty($_POST[$field_key]) ) {
        $customer->update_meta_data( $field_key, sanitize_text_field($_POST[$field_key]) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.